# how do i safeguard my program from another exception while handling the same one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

```
try:
    grossCheck = int(input("How much? (figures only pls.)\n"))
except ValueError:
    grossCheck = int(input("How much? (FIGURES ONLY PLS.)\n"))

tenPees = grossCheck * 0.1
realPees = grossCheck - tenPees

print("you've got " + str(realPees))
```

i got:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'w'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

The thing is I just previously handled the same exception. 
I'm trying to handle it in case the user still enters the wrong value(s) multiple times without breaking the program.

Comment: You need to show your code, and the complete traceback. Given data is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow handle the exception. One way is to keep asking:

```
try: 
    grossCheck = int(input("How much? (figures only pls.)\n")) 
except ValueError: 
    while True:
        try: 
            grossCheck = int(input("How much? (FIGURES ONLY PLS.)\n"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: Why do you repeat code in try and catch block, check my answer to see better way of handling errors

Comment: I repeat since OP repeated and I replicated his functionality but fixed the bug he was asking about. Also note he has different strings in the `input`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can change string as you want, but while loop shouldn't be inside except block, what if you have 5 error excepts instead of ValueError, than you would need to have, in each except, five more excepts for each error

Comment: Well as said (and perhaps you need to be told this) I answered his question and nothing else. SO is *not* a code writing service. Your way of doing it *might* be better but it does not answer his question.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you, i am just suggesting to you both, how the code should be written, and my code do answer his question, since it handles error properly

Comment: Well 1. Your code does *not* "safeguard my program from another exception *while* handling the same one", and 2. How can you say you don't want to argue when your first comment was "my solution is better". That is exactly how you start an argument.

Comment: That comment was from my first answer, when he didn't put any code to his question ,so i was guessing that he didn't properly set Except blocks.
When i said  "check my answer to see better way of handling errors"  it doesn't mean that your code isn't good, it just mean that mine is better and more practical

Answer (score 0):

```
while 1:
    try:
        grossCheck = int(input("How much? (figures only pls.)\n"))
        tenPees = grossCheck * 0.1
        realPees = grossCheck - tenPees

        print("you've got " + str(realPees))
    except ValueError:
        print('You must enter number')
```

This is one of proper ways of handling errors.
The error you get, is because you have putted input in except block, you shouldn't do that, in except block you should print error,if you want, or just repeat try block